# Print specific array key

Tags: php, arrays

I need to use a key from an array for a check.

The array comes from a PDO query like this

```
function getProject($proj_id) {
    $database = new Database();
    $database->query( "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE proj_id = '$proj_id' LIMIT 1" );
    $project = $database->resultSet();
    return $project;
}
```

Then I print the array which works like it should.

```
$project = getProject(1);
print_r($project);

Array ( [0] => Array ( [proj_id] => 73 [proj_name] => Cake )
```

But when I try to print a specific key from the array like this:

```
print_r($project['proj_name'];
```

Nothing gets printed on the screen.  Why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [proj_id] => 73 [proj_name] => Cake )
  ^--this one    ^--and this one
```

You need to do:

```
print_r($project[0]['proj_name']);
```

Probably the ideal situation would actually be to change it here:

```
function getProject($proj_id) {
  $database = new Database();
  $database->query( "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE proj_id = '$proj_id' LIMIT 1" );
  $project = $database->resultSet();
  return $project[0]; //<---added the [0] this line 
}
```

since you know it will always return one

Comment: But where does that second array come from?

Comment: Your `resultSet()` function (which is not standard) probably calls PDO's `fetchAll()`, which _always_ returns a 2D array, even for single rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully, you'll see that you have two arrays nested one inside the other. Try `print_r($project[0]['proj_name'];`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a close-paren `)` at the end of your `print_r` call.

You're seeing nothing on the screen because this means the file cannot be parsed, and errors are being logged to a file rather than displayed on screen.  See [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) for how to fix that.

Comment: While technically correct, that seems like it's just a copy-paste error, and not the actual issue.

Comment: you are right, but even with the close-paren ')' it wouldn't do what he wanted to do.

Comment: It would explain the "Nothing gets printed on the screen."  If the problem is simply that OP isn't passing the right value to `print_r()`, *something* would print.

Comment: i think it would only show a warning if you have them enabled. Otherwise it just stays blank. At least i tried it at writecodeonline and it shows nothing.